# how to write a lambda filtering and mapping list to list

Tags: java, lambda

This is origin:

```
List<Role> managedRoles = new ArrayList<>();
for (Role role : roles) {
    if (role.getManagedRole() != null) { // a list of Role.
        managedRoles.addAll(role.getManagedRole());
    }
}
```

This is what I want:

```
managedRoles = roles.stream().filter(r -> r.getManagedRole() != null).map(role -> role.getManagedRole()).collect(); // how to addAll ?
```

But `role.getManagedRole() is a List<Role>`, I think some function like `addAll` is needed. So how to make it in Lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `flatMap` instead of `map` to flatten all the `List<Role>`s returned by `role.getManagedRole()` to a single `Stream<Role>`.

```
List<Role> managedRoles = 
    roles.stream()
         .filter(r -> r.getManagedRole() != null)
         .flatMap(role -> role.getManagedRole().stream())
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: flatMap! that's it

Answer (score 0):

```
managedRoles = roles.stream()
      .filter(r -> r.getManagedRole() != null)
      .flatMap(role -> role.getManagedRole())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to generate as a list
or try this example for add elementrs to existing list

```
List<String> destList = Collections.synchronizedList(
                 new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("foo")));
List<String> newList = Arrays.asList("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
newList.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> destList));
System.out.println(destList);
```